# Разность чисел, представленных в виде строк. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Даны две строки, содержащие числа. Получите разность чисел в виде строки.

Напишите функцию с именем `differenceOfStr`, которая принимает два числа `a` и `b` в форме строк в качестве аргументов и
 возвращает строку, содержащую разность чисел.

Примеры:

- функция `differenceOfStr('5', '3')` должна возвратить `"2"`;
- функция `differenceOfStr('1.25', '3')` должна возвратить `"-1.75"`.

```
function differenceOfStr(a, b){
 return a - b;
}

differenceOfStr('5', '3');
differenceOfStr('1.25', '3');
```

**Я понять не могу и найти не могу как из числа вернуть строку. Подскажите пожалуйста.**

Comment: `return (a - b).toString()`

Comment: спасибо, где можно про JS изучить как все работает с примерами и задачами? кроме как справочник JS.

Comment: @РомаМедведев Например, [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/).

Comment: со сложением только вот так не прокатит, если что.

Comment: @teran Попрошу без спойлеров :) Самое интересное впереди!

Comment: @РомаМедведев Для совсем маленьких есть книжка "Изучаем программирование на JavaScript" Робсона Элизабет и Фримена Эрика. Есть ещё "Выразительный JavaScript" для не совсем нулёвых. Для людей с каким-никаким опытом есть "Как устроен JavaScript" Дугласа Крокфорда. Ну и для уверенных в себе молодых людей, есть серия книг "Вы не знаете JS" с полным доступом на русском вот [здесь](https://github.com/azat-io/you-dont-know-js-ru)